# What is the PHP equivalent of Javascript's undefined?

Tags: php, null

My assumption followed by question based on the assumption:

Javascript has `null` and `undefined`. You can set a variable to be `null`, implying it has no value, or you can set it to `undefined`, implying that it isn't known whether it has a value or not - it's just not set at all.

PHP has `null`, which so far I've used in the same way I'd use `null` in Javascript. Does PHP have an equivalent of `undefined`?

Comment: Voting to "reopen" as a question at +5 is surely interesting (and the problem is clear, to me at least)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really, `undefined` has no counterpart in PHP. Comparing JS's `undefined` to PHP
s `null` doesn't really stack up, but it's as close as you're going to get. In both languages you can assign these values/non-values:

```
var nothingness = undefined;
$nothing = null;
```

and, if you declare a variable, but don't assign it anything, it would appear that JS resolves the var to `undefined`, and PHP resolves (or assigns) that variable `null`:

```
var nothingness;
console.log(nothingness === undefined);//true

$foo;
echo is_null($foo) ? 'is null' : '?';//is null
```

Be careful with `isset`, though:

```
$foo = null;
//clearly, foo is set:
if (isset($foo))
{//will never echo
    echo 'foo is set';
}
```

The only *real* way to know if the variable exists, AFAIK, is by using `get_defined_vars`:

```
$foo;
$bar = null;
$defined = get_defined_vars();
if (array_key_exists($defined, 'foo'))
{
    echo '$foo was defined, and assigned: '.$foo;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is `undefined`. Rather than checking if something is `undefined` as you would in JavaScript:

```
if(object.property === undefined) // Doesn't exist.
```

You just use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if(!isset($something)) // Doesn't exist.
```

Also, I think your understanding of `undefined` is a little odd. You shouldn't be *setting* properties to `undefined`, that's illogical. You just want to *check* if something is undefined, which means you haven't defined it anywhere within scope. `isset()` follows this concept.

That said, you can use [`unset()`](https://www.php.net/unset) which I guess would be considered the same as setting something to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some scenarios where the `null` is a valid value, and there needs to be some other data type to signify the result of an action.

For example, I have a function to get the value of some key in a complex/nested array. The key value can be anything (including `null`). What should I return in this case if the key path is not valid? Returning `null`, `false`, `-1`, etc. wouldn't make any sense because the key value might be one of these.

What I decided to is define a constant:

```php
define("undefined", "__undefined__");
...
$value = getKeyValue($options, ["section", "subsection", "opt2"]);
if ($value != undefined) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It only has "unset", which is not actually a value at all.

Comment: Isn't unset the same as `null`?

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe: `null` is an actual value. Unset variables simply result in null when dumping them, and variables with the value of `null` appear unset.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is the value you'll get in Javascript when trying to access a property/variable which does not exist. You don't typically *set* something to `undefined`.

PHP does not have this mechanism. If you're trying to access a property or variable which does not exist, you will trigger an error of the level `E_NOTICE`. The script will continue, but the value of the non-existent variable will be substituted by `null`.

In Javascript you try to access a variable and test whether it you get `undefined` or not.
In PHP, you use `isset($var)` to test whether a variable exists before accessing it.